# How to save easily all request data after validation in laravel, See my code please

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

**My Controller:**

```
public function chamberProcess(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'hospital_name' => 'required',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'end_time' => 'required',
            'start_day' => 'required',
            'end_day' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'limit' => 'required'
        ]);

        $chamberinfo = new DoctorChamber;

        $chamberinfo->hospital_name = $request->hospital_name;
        $chamberinfo->start_time = $request->start_time;
        $chamberinfo->end_time = $request->end_time;
        $chamberinfo->start_day = $request->start_day;
        $chamberinfo->end_day = $request->end_day;
        $chamberinfo->address = $request->address;
        $chamberinfo->limit = $request->limit;
        $chamberinfo->save();

        return redirect(route('viewchamber'));
    }
```

**I don't want to write the bellow codes:**

```
$chamberinfo->hospital_name = $request->hospital_name;
$chamberinfo->start_time = $request->start_time;
$chamberinfo->end_time = $request->end_time;
$chamberinfo->start_day = $request->start_day;
$chamberinfo->end_day = $request->end_day;
$chamberinfo->address = $request->address;
$chamberinfo->limit = $request->limit;
```

**It works fine but I want $request all or something like this. When I add 100 data then should I write 100 line of avobe code? Ofcourse there is solution but I don't know. Please help me!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
DoctorChamber::create($request->all());
```

Comment: this is dangerous

Answer (score 3):

```
$chamberinfo = DoctorChamber::create($request->validated());
```

Comment: Could you explain what this line of code does?

Comment: The `validated()` method returns an array of validated input data: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#working-with-validated-input